# Unexpected Logout on Ubuntu 14.04 (or is it X crash?)

Tags: 14.04, logout

maybe once a day it happens. It is an unexpected log out. Not sure where to find the error, or what to look for. Is there a power buttton problem?

this is the content of Xorg.0.log.old
...

```
[ 22560.587]  
X.Org X Server 1.15.1 
Release Date: 2014-04-13 
[ 22560.587] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0 
[ 22560.587] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[ 22560.587] Current Operating System: Linux laura-at-work 3.13.0-63-generic #103-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 14 21:42:59 UTC 2015 x86_64
[ 22560.587] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic root=UUID=4bd47f21-00ba-4e9d-87c3-04d06399187e ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[ 22560.587] Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
[ 22560.587] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[ 22560.587] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[ 22560.587]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 22560.587] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 22560.587] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Sep 19 15:12:24 2015
[ 22560.588] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 22560.589] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[ 22560.589] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[ 22560.589] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[ 22560.589] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[ 22560.590] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
Using a default monitor configuration.
[ 22560.590] (==) Automatically adding devices
[ 22560.590] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 22560.590] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 22560.591] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[ 22560.591]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 22560.591] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[ 22560.591]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 22560.591] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[ 22560.591]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 22560.592] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[ 22560.592]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 22560.592] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[ 22560.592]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 22560.592] (==) FontPath set to:
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
built-ins
[ 22560.592] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[ 22560.592] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
 [ 22560.592] (II) Loader magic: 0x7fdad05b8d40
 [ 22560.592] (II) Module ABI versions:
 [ 22560.592]   X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
 [ 22560.592]   X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
 [ 22560.592]   X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
 [ 22560.592]   X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
 [ 22560.592] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
 [ 22560.593] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0156:1458:d000 rev 9, Mem @ 0xf7800000/4194304, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension Present
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
 [ 22560.594] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
 [ 22560.594] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
 [ 22560.596] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
 [ 22560.598] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [ 22560.598]   compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
 [ 22560.598]   ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
 [ 22560.598] (==) AIGLX enabled
 [ 22560.599] Loading extension GLX
 [ 22560.599] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
 [ 22560.599] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
 [ 22560.599] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
 [ 22560.599] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
 [ 22560.599] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
 [ 22560.599] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
 [ 22560.599] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
 [ 22560.599] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
 [ 22560.605] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [ 22560.605]   compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 2.99.910
 [ 22560.605]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [ 22560.605]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [ 22560.605] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
 [ 22560.606] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
 [ 22560.606] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [ 22560.606]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
 [ 22560.606]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [ 22560.606]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [ 22560.606] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
 [ 22560.606] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
 [ 22560.607] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [ 22560.607]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
 [ 22560.607]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [ 22560.607]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [ 22560.607] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
 [ 22560.607] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
 [ 22560.607] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [ 22560.607]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
 [ 22560.607]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [ 22560.607]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [ 22560.607] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
 [ 22560.608] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
 [ 22560.608] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
 [ 22560.608] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
 [ 22560.608] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
 [ 22560.608] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
 [ 22560.608] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
 [ 22560.608] (++) using VT number 7

 [ 22560.636] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1.6 (Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@debian.org>)
 [ 22560.637] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
 [ 22560.637] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
 [ 22560.637] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
 [ 22560.637] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
 [ 22560.637] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
 [ 22560.645] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [ 22560.645]   compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
 [ 22560.645]   ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
 [ 22560.645] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
 [ 22560.646] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 2500
 [ 22560.646] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2
 [ 22560.646] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
"Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
 [ 22560.646] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
 [ 22560.646] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
 [ 22560.646] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
 [ 22560.648] (**) intel(0): Framebuffer tiled
 [ 22560.648] (**) intel(0): Pixmaps tiled
 [ 22560.648] (**) intel(0): "Tear free" disabled
 [ 22560.648] (**) intel(0): Forcing per-crtc-pixmaps? no
 [ 22560.648] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 has no monitor section
 [ 22560.648] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
 [ 22560.648] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 has no monitor section
 [ 22560.648] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
 [ 22560.648] (--) intel(0): Output HDMI1 using initial mode 1280x1024 on pipe 0
 [ 22560.648] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
 [ 22560.648] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
 [ 22560.648] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
 [ 22560.648] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
 [ 22560.648] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
 [ 22560.648] (II) Unloading modesetting
 [ 22560.648] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
 [ 22560.648] (II) Unloading fbdev
 [ 22560.648] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
 [ 22560.648] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
 [ 22560.648] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
 [ 22560.648] (II) Unloading vesa
 [ 22560.648] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
 [ 22560.666] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Ivybridge (gen7, gt1) backend
 [ 22560.666] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
 [ 22560.666] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
 [ 22560.667] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
 [ 22560.667] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
 [ 22560.668] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
 [ 22560.668] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
 [ 22560.668] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
 [ 22560.668] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: i965
 [ 22560.668] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 Enabled
 [ 22560.668] (==) intel(0): hotplug detection: "enabled"
 [ 22560.668] (--) RandR disabled
 [ 22560.687] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
 [ 22560.708] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
 [ 22560.708] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
 [ 22560.708] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
 [ 22560.708] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile
 [ 22560.708] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
 [ 22560.708] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
 [ 22560.708] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
 [ 22560.708] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
 [ 22560.708] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
 [ 22560.708] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
 [ 22560.708] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
 [ 22560.708] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
 [ 22560.711] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1280x1024@60.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
 [ 22560.732] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 338 x 270
 [ 22560.760] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
 [ 22560.767] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
 [ 22560.767] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
 [ 22560.767] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
 [ 22560.767] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
 [ 22560.768] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [ 22560.768]   compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.8.2
 [ 22560.768]   Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
 [ 22560.768]   ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 20.0
 [ 22560.768] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
 [ 22560.768] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
 [ 22560.768] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
 [ 22560.768] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
 [ 22560.768] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
 [ 22560.768] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
 [ 22560.768] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
 [ 22560.768] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
 [ 22560.768] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
 [ 22560.768] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
 [ 22560.768] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
 [ 22560.769] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event5)
 [ 22560.769] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
 [ 22560.769] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
 [ 22560.769] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
 [ 22560.769] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
 [ 22560.769] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
 [ 22560.769] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
 [ 22560.769] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
 [ 22560.769] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input8/event5"
 [ 22560.769] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
 [ 22560.769] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
 [ 22560.769] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
 [ 22560.769] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
 [ 22560.770] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
 [ 22560.770] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
 [ 22560.770] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
 [ 22560.770] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
 [ 22560.770] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
 [ 22560.770] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
 [ 22560.770] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
 [ 22560.770] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
 [ 22560.770] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
 [ 22560.770] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
 [ 22560.770] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
 [ 22560.770] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
 [ 22560.770] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
 [ 22560.771] (II) config/udev: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0) card0 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0
 [ 22560.771] (II) config/udev: Ignoring already known drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
 [ 22560.771] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event2)
 [ 22560.771] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
 [ 22560.771] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard'
 [ 22560.771] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: always reports core events
 [ 22560.771] (**) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
 [ 22560.771] (--) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Vendor 0x4ca Product 0x5b
 [ 22560.771] (--) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Found keys
 [ 22560.771] (II) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
 [ 22560.771] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/input/input5/event2"
 [ 22560.771] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
 [ 22560.771] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
 [ 22560.771] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
 [ 22560.771] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
 [ 22560.772] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
 [ 22560.772] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
 [ 22560.772] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard'
 [ 22560.772] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: always reports core events
 [ 22560.772] (**) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
 [ 22560.772] (--) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Vendor 0x4ca Product 0x5b
 [ 22560.772] (--) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Found 1 mouse buttons
 [ 22560.772] (--) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Found scroll wheel(s)
 [ 22560.772] (--) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Found relative axes
 [ 22560.772] (II) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Forcing relative x/y axes to exist.
 [ 22560.772] (--) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Found absolute axes
 [ 22560.772] (II) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Forcing absolute x/y axes to exist.
 [ 22560.772] (--) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Found keys
 [ 22560.772] (II) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Configuring as mouse
 [ 22560.772] (II) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
 [ 22560.772] (II) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Adding scrollwheel support
 [ 22560.772] (**) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
 [ 22560.772] (**) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
 [ 22560.772] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/input/input6/event3"
 [ 22560.772] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
 [ 22560.772] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
 [ 22560.773] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
 [ 22560.773] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
 [ 22560.773] (II) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: initialized for relative axes.
 [ 22560.773] (WW) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: ignoring absolute axes.
 [ 22560.773] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
 [ 22560.773] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: (accel) acceleration profile 0
 [ 22560.773] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
 [ 22560.773] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
 [ 22560.774] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Laser Mouse (/dev/input/event4)
 [ 22560.774] (**) Logitech USB Laser Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
 [ 22560.774] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech USB Laser Mouse'
 [ 22560.774] (**) Logitech USB Laser Mouse: always reports core events
 [ 22560.774] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Laser Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
 [ 22560.774] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Laser Mouse: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xc069
 [ 22560.774] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Laser Mouse: Found 12 mouse buttons
 [ 22560.774] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Laser Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
 [ 22560.774] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Laser Mouse: Found relative axes
 [ 22560.774] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Laser Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
 [ 22560.774] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Laser Mouse: Configuring as mouse
 [ 22560.774] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Laser Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[ 22560.774] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Laser Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[ 22560.774] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Laser Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[ 22560.774] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.2/1-1.3.2:1.0/input/input7/event4"
[ 22560.774] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Laser Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 11)
[ 22560.774] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Laser Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[ 22560.775] (**) Logitech USB Laser Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[ 22560.775] (**) Logitech USB Laser Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[ 22560.775] (**) Logitech USB Laser Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[ 22560.775] (**) Logitech USB Laser Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[ 22560.775] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Laser Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[ 22560.775] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 22560.775] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 22560.775] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Mic (/dev/input/event10)
[ 22560.775] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 22560.775] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 22560.776] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line (/dev/input/event9)
[ 22560.776] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 22560.776] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 22560.776] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out (/dev/input/event8)
[ 22560.776] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 22560.776] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 22560.776] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event7)
[ 22560.776] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 22560.776] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 22560.776] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event6)
[ 22560.776] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 22560.777] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 22560.777] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic (/dev/input/event11)
[ 22560.777] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 22560.777] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 22561.751] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "DEL", prod id 16405
[ 22561.751] (II) intel(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[ 22561.751] (II) intel(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
[ 22561.751] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[ 22561.751] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[ 22561.751] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[ 22561.751] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[ 22561.751] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[ 22561.751] (II) intel(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[ 22561.751] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[ 22561.751] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[ 22561.751] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[ 22561.751] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[ 22561.751] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[ 22585.361] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[ 22585.502] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
 [ 22585.583] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[ 22588.289] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-34CEB476A3CB596DA76FD7010A029F76732EF824.xkm
[ 28175.740] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1280x1024@60.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 31705.244] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1280x1024@60.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 37727.946] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1280x1024@60.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 37902.480] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1280x1024@60.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 38228.640] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-34CEB476A3CB596DA76FD7010A029F76732EF824.xkm
[ 38228.653] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[ 45552.884] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1280x1024@60.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 47535.292] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1280x1024@60.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 51839.791] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1280x1024@60.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 52973.779] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1280x1024@60.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 58614.060] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1280x1024@60.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 59376.174] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1280x1024@60.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 60944.079] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Laser Mouse: Close
[ 60944.080] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[ 60944.080] (II) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Close
[ 60944.080] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[ 60944.080] (II) evdev: Lite-On Technology Corp. Goldtouch USB Keyboard: Close
[ 60944.080] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[ 60944.080] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[ 60944.080] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[ 60944.080] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Close
[ 60944.080] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[ 60944.080] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[ 60944.081] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[ 60944.139] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Comment: will you please use [edit help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) while posting question at least for the next time.